# Trying to compile a program with boost, it wants libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_38.lib when it should want libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_38.lib

Tags: c++, boost

I am using VS2010 using the v100 platform toolset targeting a 64-bit build. When I compile it seems to want the vc90-X lib files opposed to the vc100-X files it should be looking for. I'm not sure what code even tells it what lib files to look for, how do I tell it to look for the files I have?

I'm assuming I should not be building the vc90 files as that is for an older version of my compiler.

Comment: Was your Boost distribution built using VS2008 (VC9)? And Boost 1.38? That's almost 4 years old!

Comment: I used boostpro, I checked VS2010 during the installation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BoostPro distro's directory structure, but there should be a single sub-directory in it with all the libraries. The file names should have *vc100* in them if you have the correct version.

Comment: They all do. My compiler is looking for the vc90-X files though.

Comment: The simple explanation is that it wants both.  The "vc90" part of the name is generated from the compiler version macro, _MSC_VER.  Have a look-see at boost/config/auto_link.hpp for the macro soup.  Which leaves only one explanation, you are linking code that was compiled with VS2008.  You'll need to rebuild *all* of the libraries with VS2010.